# Horizontal Line in Array

Tags: math-mode, matrices, line, horizontal

Good evening,

I'm trying to achieve following picture in latex, but i can't do it. Can someone help me?
[image]

This is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[utf8] {inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
      $\left(\begin{array}{rrrr}
             2&2&-1&3  \\
            \cmidrule{2-4}
             0&1&3&4  \\
             0&1&3&4  \\
             0&3&9&6  \\
             0&1&3&-2  
    \end{array}\right)$
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're missing the vertical line `|` in the column specification and a `\multicolumn{1}{r}` for the element in the top left corner:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
  \left(
    \begin{array}{ r | *{3}{r} }
      \multicolumn{1}{r}{2} & 2 & -1 &  3 \\
      \cline{2-4}
      0 & 1 &  3 &  4 \\
      0 & 1 &  3 &  4 \\
      0 & 3 &  9 &  6 \\
      0 & 1 &  3 & -2  
    \end{array}
  \right)
\]

\end{document}
```

For a more evenly distributed spacing around the last three columns, consider using `\phantom{-}2` in the first row:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
  \left(
    \begin{array}{ r | *{3}{r} }
      \multicolumn{1}{r}{2} & \phantom{-}2 & -1 &  3 \\
      \cline{2-4}
      0 & 1 &  3 &  4 \\
      0 & 1 &  3 &  4 \\
      0 & 3 &  9 &  6 \\
      0 & 1 &  3 & -2  
    \end{array}
  \right)
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much !

Answer (score 10):

With `nicematrix`. The environments of `nicematrix` create PGF/Tikz nodes under the rows, columns and cells and the array and it's possible to use them to draw whatever you want with Tikz.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{pNiceMatrix}[r,right-margin,columns-width=auto]
  2 & 2 & -1 &  3 \\
  0 & 1 &  3 &  4 \\
  0 & 1 &  3 &  4 \\
  0 & 3 &  9 &  6 \\
  0 & 1 &  3 & -2  
\CodeAfter
\tikz \draw ([xshift=4pt]last-|2) |- (2-|last) ;
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Is it also possible to draw dotted lines ?

Comment: @Francesco: Yes. Put `\draw [dotted]` instead of `\draw`.

Comment: To my eyes the horizontal line is a little too low.

Comment: @Anush That's why this approach is more powerful. You only need e.g. `\tikz \draw ([xshift=4pt]row-6-|col-2) |- ([yshift=2pt]row-2-|col-5) ;`, or whatever `yshift` you like. And have access to many other things such as decorated lines.